# How to redirect back after logout, unless page needs authentication?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm already familiar with the Redirect::back(); command for Laravel. Which I saw in my initial searches, but I was wondering on how to redirect away from an authenticated page after Redirect::back(); works on it.

This is the logout of the AuthController

```
public function logout()
{
    $accessToken = auth()->user()->token();

    $refreshToken = DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
    ->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)
    ->update([
        'revoked' => true
    ]);

    $accessToken->revoke();

    // REDIRECTS USERS BACK TO THE PAGE THEY LOGGED OUT OF
    Redirect::back();
    return response()->json(['status' => 200]);
}
```

I already set the route to reroute

```
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: require('./../views/dashboard.vue'),
    meta: {
        middlewareAuth: true
    }
}
```

along with

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.middlewareAuth)) {
    if (!auth.check()) {
        next({
            path: '/login',
            query: {
                redirect: to.fullPath
            }
        });
        return;
    }
}
next();
})
```

To redirect away when a user clicks on it and is working.

What I want to happen as an example is the following

Home -> Logout -> Home [WORKS]
Dashboard -> Logout -> Home [DOESN'T WORK] 
Redirects back to Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming from Dashboard, then Redirect back should be trying to send you back to dashboard, which it sounds like it's doing. If you want it to go to the home page, you could specify redirect to go to home instead.

Comment: I get that, but I thought that the middleware would catch it and then redirect it to login, considering that you're not supposed to be able to access dashboard without logging in.

Comment: Oh, so you're able to view dashboard when you're logged out, even though you're only supposed to view it when you're logged in? That definitely sounds like an authentication issue with how your middleware is set up for dashboard.